# double roots with Newton-raphson method

Tags: newton-raphson

While working on an engineering problem, we have met a non linear system of two variables and two equations.

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
A=x \sin y \\ 
B=-x^2 + x \cos y 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
where $A$ and $B$ are constants.

if the system is solved analytically two solutions ($Z1$ and $Z2$) can be found from:
$(A^2+B^2)+Z^2+Z(2B -1) =0 $

where $Z=x^2$

but if we solve the system with Newton-Raphson method only one solution is found.
How to obtain the second one?

Comment: Just detect where $y $ is poaitive and negative for two separate intervals . You will get two solutions . This can be done only if we know tge exact values of $A,B $.

Comment: The equation giving two solutions for $Z$ is not equivalent to the original system, but obtained by squaring. Are you sure the second solution is a solution of the original system?

Comment: Thank you for your answers;
@ArchisWelankar the problem is that the two solutions are positive, we need the positive solution for $y1$ and $y2$
and the exact values of $A$ and $B$ are known.

Comment: Thank you for your answers;
@ProfessorVector we are juste using $Z$ as a change of variable to help find the solutions of the original system. 
the equation using $Z$ has in fact 4 solutions (2 positive solutions and 2 negative solutions) we only need the two positive ones of the system.
yes the second solution is a solution of the original system.

Comment: Then you need to determine the nature of the graph (like increasing) or otherwise you need to use to different starting points.